# drawbitmap from painting on a win form

Tags: c#, winforms, capture, drawtobitmap

i have a Windows-Form, i need to draw some lines and rectangles to show a shape on the form. 
i want to capture this shown paintings to store them in Database
the method i use for capture is :

```
internal void CapturePartition()
    {
        Bitmap PartitionImage = new Bitmap(lblRight.Location.X+lblRight.Width, lblPartitionWidth.Location.Y+lblPartitionWidth.Height);
        this.DrawToBitmap(PartitionImage, new Rectangle(lblPartitionName.Location.X, lblPartitionName.Location.Y, lblRight.Location.X + lblRight.Width, lblPartitionWidth.Location.Y + lblPartitionWidth.Height));
        //PartitionImage.Save(Globals.ProjectName + "1", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        Bitmap ResizedPartitionImage = new Bitmap(PartitionImage, new Size(200, 200));
        MemoryStream MS = new MemoryStream();
        ResizedPartitionImage.Save(MS, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        PartiionBinary = new System.Data.Linq.Binary(MS.GetBuffer());
    }
```

but after capturing image is empty just showing forms background
whats wrong?

Comment: Do you draw your stuff in the Paint event, using the `e.Graphics` object? If not, you need to!

Comment: @TaW they was in createGraphics, i currected them. issue solved but, i have another problem also now, i am using some Graphics.clip & Graphics.clear methodes to fill a shape with color, the problem is after that first clep & clear performs, then no drawline and drawrectangle works any more

Comment: Well, in this case I guess you can edit the question, adding the Paint code. Without seeing the code one could only guess. ((Before unclipped drawing with a clipped graphics again one usually needs to ResetClip))

Comment: i used a fillrectangle command instead of clip & clear, and it solved problem 

Comment: Good. Btw: Do try to save as png if you want legible text or unblurred vertical lines in your screenshot..!